# Azure PowerShell clipboard usage

Tags: powershell, azure

I am using Azure PowerShell and many times I am operating with clipboard data.

Is there any convenient way to insert clipboard content as a command line except the way unproductive mouse based *"Click window top left -> Edit -> Paste"* ?

Comment: By enabling [QuickEdit Mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/317591) for PowerShell?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Any chance without mouse, it's a _console_...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which shell is launched for Azure Powershell, but in a normal Powershell host either of these methods will work:

1. Right click on the mouse
2. The combination <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> , <kbd>e</kbd> , <kbd>p</kbd>

If the right click on the mouse doesn't work, perhaps try modifying your Powershell [profile](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_profile_ps1.htm) to include the Azure module, and then use the Azure cmdlets from the default host.